# How to insert text after a certain string in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Right now I'm using

```
echo "Hello World" >> file.txt
```

to append some text to a file but I also need to add text below a certain string let's say `[option]`, is it possible with `sed`?

EG:

Input file

```
Some text
Random
[option]
Some stuff
```

Output file

```
Some text
Random
[option]
*inserted text*
Some stuff
```

Comment: You have to be more specific and give some sample text for people to help you with exact commands.

Comment: please edit you Q and show the `input` and the `output` lines. Because you Q is unclear. You could also do `echo "Hello World [option]" >> file.txt`, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I edited the question to provide more information for reference but the accepted answer was what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: If you just want to **edit a config file** this is the best solution I found: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78076/20661

Answer (score 173, accepted):

**Append line after match**

- `sed  '/\[option\]/a Hello World' input`

**Insert line before match**

- `sed  '/\[option\]/i Hello World' input`

Additionally you can take backup and edit input file in-place using `-i.bkp` option to sed

Comment: on osx i get `sed: 1: "/pattern/a some text here": command a expects \ followed by text
`

Comment: @the_prole https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229873/how-to-fix-command-a-expects-followed-by-text-in-my-sed

Comment: for Mac OSX, I needed to add `\ <<NEWLINE>>` after the `a` option

Comment: The above code will append/insert the line for every single match. If you want to append/insert the line for the first match only, you can prepend `0,` to the commands: `sed  '0,/\[option\]/a Hello World' input` or `sed  '0,/\[option\]/i Hello World' input`

Comment: @kimbaudi I'm not sure why, but in my case merely adding `0,` inserts the line all over the file without any noticeable pattern (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/54382514)

Comment: Works for me and if you want insert space it may like `sed  '/\[option\]/a \ \ Hello World' input`

Comment: To save it in the file add the i flag like `sed -i '/match-after-I-put-mystuff/a mystuff' file-with-new-stuff

Comment: If the appended string is a multiline text u can save it to a file (e.g.: snippet.txt)  and inject this file after the pattern using: `sed -i '/pattern/ r snippet.txt' filename`

Comment: /a does not work for all OS and sed versions. I found the solution which seems to be general, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69873897/4807875.

Answer (score 54):

Yes, it is possible with `sed`:

```
sed '/pattern/a some text here' filename
```

An example:

```
$ cat test
foo
bar
option
baz
$ sed '/option/a insert text here' test
foo
bar
option
insert text here
baz
$
```

Comment: Doesn't work on mac... Error: `command a expects \ followed by text`

Answer (score 10):

With `awk`:

```
awk '1;/PATTERN/{ print "add one line"; print "\\and one more"}' infile
```

Keep in mind that some characters can not be included literally so one has to use *escape sequences* (they begin with a backslash) e.g. to print a literal backslash one has to write `\\`.

It's actually the same with `sed` but in addition each embedded newline in the text has to be preceded by a backslash:

```
sed '/PATTERN/a\
add one line\
\\and one more' infile
```

For more details on escape sequences consult the manual.

---

Also, to address some of the comments: the above commands DO NOT edit the file in place, they just print the result to the standard output. To actually  modify the input file you would either use the `-i` switch if your `awk`/`sed` support it (consult the manual) or redirect to a temporary file then overwrite the original e.g.

```
cmd infile > outfile
mv outfile infile
```

Or use `ed`/`ex` which can edit the files in-place on all platforms:

```
ex -s infile <<\IN
/PATTERN/a
add one line
and one more
.
w
q
IN
```

Remember: with `ed`/`sed`/`ex`, `a` appends and `i` inserts; with `awk`, to insert, move the `1` to the end.

Comment: An awk line does not actually change the text, only output.

Comment: To change text in a file (replace inline), use `awk -i inline ...`

Comment: Notes: to modify a file in-place (and avoid emptying the input file), this `awk` output should be piped to a file, which should be copied after its done back to the same file; PATTERN should not be surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using the `ed` utility. It's easier to use `sed` but nice to be familiar with an additional utility (I came to this page, specifically looking how to achieve this using ed; I already knew how to do it in sed).

For your example file (printed with line numbers for reference):

```
 1  Some text
 2  Random
 3  [option]
 4  Some stuff
```

The `ed` commands to achieve the suggested output would be:

```
4i
*inserted text*
.
w
q
```

Explanation:

1. go to line 4, start insert mode (i)
2. add **inserted text** (including the newline)
3. exit insert mode (.)
4. write the file (w) and quit `ed` (q)

You can put this all together in one command using a [here string](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_strings):

```
ed filename.txt <<< '4i
*inserted text*
.
w
q
'
```