# How to fix 'command a expects \ followed by text' in my sed on MacOS?

Tags: sed, osx

I have the following snippet in a sed statement:

```
/pause$/ {
  N;
  /pause/d
}
```

but I'm getting:

```
$ . sed_shorter_version_one_test_case_html_to_ruby.sh SAD/fullform_SAD
sed: 19: "
/pause$/ {
  N;
  /pau ...": command a expects \ followed by text
```

Why is that? How to fix?

Comment: wherever `a` is in your sed statement place a \ after the a then a newline and the text you want to append.

Comment: @Mark, I'm voting to leave this closed as it appears that the typo was in a separate section of the sed script (doesn't appear in the Question, at least)

Comment: note that this only works within double quotes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had

```
$ a\end
```

at the bottom

I had to change it to

```
$ a\
end
```

Comment: Not sure why this got rejected as this is a legitimate case on OSX. Thanks for sharing your solution.