# How to insert text after a certain string in a file (on OSX)?

Tags: text-processing, osx

I have followed instructions in this post [How to insert text after a certain string in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121161/how-to-insert-text-after-a-certain-string-in-a-file)

but I suspect the instructions are not valid for OSX.

I want to add some text into a source file using Bash

```
sed '/pattern/a some text here' ${sourceFile}
```

but when I run the command I get

> "/pattern/a some text here": command a expects \ followed by text

**edit**

I have created a new file called `infile` with a single line

```
pattern
```

and a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '/pattern/a\
text to insert' infile
```

running the script echos "pattern" to the console but doesn't insert the text

**edit**

I have also tried for the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '/pattern/a\
add one line\
\\and one more' infile
```

and the terminal echos

```
pattern
add one line
\and one more
```

but infile still has single line

```
pattern
```

Comment: The portable way to do it (with any `sed`, including the OSX one) is in my post there...

Comment: If the pattern matches a string in the infile, terminal echos print statment, but print statement is not inserted into infile `awk '1;/pattern/{ print "add one line"; print "\\and one more"}' infile`

Comment: this is true of sed example as well

Comment: You need to save the edits with the -i option to sed. Otw, save it to a temp file nd move it back to the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if OSX has `ed` (found one [positive hint](https://ss64.com/osx/)), so here's another option:

```
grep -q pattern infile && ed -s infile  <<< $'/pattern/\na\ntext to insert\n.\nw\nq' > /dev/null
```

This sends the following commands to `ed`:

1. `/pattern/` -- search for "pattern"
2. `a` -- append the following text after that line
3. `text to insert` -- the text
4. `.` -- end of the inserted text
5. `w` -- write the updated file to disk
6. `q` -- quit ed

The `>/dev/null` redirection is to silence `ed`'s report of the matching `pattern` line.

I've prefixed the `ed` command with a quiet `grep` to ensure that "pattern" exists in the file before asking `ed` to search for it -- otherwise, you'll get a confused `?` from `ed` when the pattern search fails.

Comment: The problem is the command doesn't seem to work with double quotes so I don't appear to be able to perform string interpolation `$'/pattern/\na\ntext to insert\n.\nw\nq'`

Comment: start and end the interpolation where you want to insert text: `$'/pattern/...'"your text here"$'\n.\nw\nq'`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the `-i` the in-place editing option of `sed`. Because sed is a `stream editor` so will not make any changes to the input. You need to explicitly make the efforts to move the output file back to the input or use the -i option if available:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '' -e '/pattern/a\
add one line\
\\and one more' \
infile
```