# Change a value in a config file, or add the setting if it doesn't exist?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, scripting, configuration

When modifying config files from the command line, I often want to find the setting in the config file and modify that line if that setting exists.   If that setting doesn't exist, I want to add it to the end of the file.

I end up doing something like:

```
if [ `grep -c '^setting=' example.conf` == 0 ]
then 
    echo "setting=value" >> example.conf
else 
    sed -i 's/^setting=.*/setting=value/g' example.conf
fi
```

Which seems like an awful lot of code for something so simple.   This doesn't even do basic things like check that the config file already ends in a new line before appending to it.   Surely there is a utility that does this, or a simpler command that I can use.

Comment: It is simpler to use `if grep -q 'pattern' file` instead of `if [ $(grep -c ...) -eq 0 ]`.

Comment: Is your config file only content `settings=values`?

Comment: The config file that I'm working with has settings with values and comment lines, but no sections.

Comment: This is subjective, but I prefer to add some extra lines rather than make a hard-to-read one-liner.

Comment: Also, if this works perfectly for you, then just put it in a script in your `$PATH` and you've made your own utility.

Comment: If you just want to **edit a config file** this is the best solution I found: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78076/20661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a confset Perl script that I just wrote that I'm going to put in my path:

- Can work with multiple files in a single invocation
- Can modify multiple config values in each file in a single invocation
- Separator can be specified (with `--separator`)
- Option to be liberal about white space around names

---

```
Usage: confset <options> name1=value1 name2=value2 file1.conf file2.conf
Options:
  -s --separator <value>        What comes between names and values (default =)
  -w --whitespace  <true|false> Allow space around names and values (default false)
```

So to the handle the case I outlined in the question, I would call it with:

```
 confset example.conf setting=value
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $scriptname = $0;
my $separator = '=';
my $whitespace = 0;

my @files = ();
my @namevalues = ();

# read in the command line arguments
for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@ARGV); $i++){
    my $arg = @ARGV[$i];
    if ($arg =~ /^-/){
        &printHelp(*STDOUT, 0) if ($arg eq "-h" or $arg eq "--help");
        &printHelp(*STDERR, 1) if ($i+1 >= scalar(@ARGV));
        my $opt = @ARGV[++$i];
        if ($arg eq "-s" or $arg eq "--separator"){
            $separator = $opt;
        } elsif ($arg eq "-w" or $arg eq "--whitespace"){
            $whitespace = 0;
            $whitespace = 1 if ($opt =~ /1|t|y/);
        } else {
            &printHelp(*STDERR, 1);
        }
    } elsif ( -e $arg){
        push(@files, $arg);
    } else {
        push(@namevalues, $arg);
    }
}

# check the validity of the command line arguments
if (scalar(@files) == 0){
    print STDERR "ERROR: No files specified\n";
    printHelp(*STDERR, 1);
}

if (scalar(@namevalues) == 0){
    print STDERR "ERROR: No name value pairs specified\n";
    printHelp(*STDERR, 1);
}

my $names = {};

foreach my $namevalue (@namevalues){
    my ($name, $value) = &splitnv($namevalue);
    if ($name){
        $names->{$name} = {"value",$value,"replaced",0};
    } else {
        print STDERR "ERROR: Argument not a file and contains no separator: $namevalue\n";
        printHelp(*STDERR, 1);
    }
}

# Do the modification to each conf file
foreach my $file (@files){

    # read in the entire file into memory
    my $contents = "";
    open FILE, $file or die $!;
    while (my $line = <FILE>){
        chomp $line;
        my ($name, $value) = &splitnv($line);
        # set matching lines to their new value
        if ($names->{$name}){
            $line = $name . $separator . $names->{$name}->{value};
            $names->{$name}->{replaced} = 1;
        }
        $contents .= "$line\n";
    }
    close FILE or die $!;

    # add any new lines that didn't already get set
    foreach my $name (keys %$names){
        if (!$names->{$name}->{replaced}){
            $contents .= $name . $separator . $names->{$name}->{value}."\n";
        }
        # reset for next file
        $names->{$name}->{replaced} = 0;
    }

    # overwrite the file
    open FILE, ">$file" or die $!;
    print FILE $contents;
    close FILE or die $!;
}

# Print help message to the specified stream and exit with the specified value
sub printHelp(){
    my ($stream, $exit) = @_;
    print $stream "Usage: $scriptname <options> name1=value1 name2=value2 file1.conf file2.conf\n";
    print $stream "Options:\n";
    print $stream "  -s --separator <value>        What comes between names and values (default =)\n";
    print $stream "  -w --whitespace  <true|false> Allow space around names and values (default false)\n";
    exit $exit;
}

# Split a string into a name and value using the global separator
sub splitnv(){
    my ($str) = @_;
    my $ind = index($str, $separator);
    return (0,0) if ($ind < 0);
    my $name = substr($str, 0, $ind);
    my $value = substr($str, $ind+length($separator));
    $name =~ s/(^[ \t])*|([ \t])*$//g if ($whitespace);
    return ($name, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra logic could be handled with `awk`.

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "=" }
$1 == "setting" { $2 = "value"; found=1 }
{print}
END { if (!found) { print "setting=value" }
```

If the property is not found by the end, then `found` won't be set and the END clause will append the new config line.  The `FS=OFS=` ensure the same format and the print will always send a newline (ORS) including the last line. Blank lines and comments would be passed through unchanged.